# Get id from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
     DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="EmptyL" AllowPaging="True" 
     AllowSorting="True" GridLines="Vertical" 
     OnRowUpdating="TaskGridView_RowUpdating">
     <Columns>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
         <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
         <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status"/>
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="EmptyLeg" runat="server" 
     ContextTypeName="Dev.Orpheus.App_Data.DataStorageDataContext" 
     EnableDelete="True" EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True" 
     EntityTypeName="" OrderBy="Id desc" TableName="EmptyL">
</asp:LinqDataSource>

protected void TaskGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = ?????? updated ID ???????
}
```

Classical gridview data from linq

For example I update the field "Status"

How to get the ID of the updated object ?

Answer (score 0):

You should get it in NewValues collection of GridViewUpdateEventArgs parameter

like this

e.NewValues["Id"]

Comment: Label1.Text = e.NewValues["Id"].ToString();

Comment: I didn't get your question

Answer (score 0):

for that you can use

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>
```

method on CheckBoxField so that in

```
protected void TaskGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = //Chechbox value
        }
```

and can update database or other filed as per necessary

Have a Good day.

Answer (score 0):

`Label1.Text = e.Keys[0]`

The grid contains a primary `.Keys` property.